# i would like to be able to type a number in a column & autofill the address in the next column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a workbook where I have a column 'site no.' where I'd like to be able to type a 3 digit number & the column 'site address' is auto filled with the address. site numbers & site address's are on sheet 2.

```
Site No.    Site address
722         A4074 Warborough
```

Site No. column is `sheet1! G:G`, that's the place I want to start typing 3 digit site address. `Sheet2! A:A` is where site numbers are `sheet2! B:B` is where the address is & `sheet1! H:H` is where I want the address to enter.

Comment: use either **VLOOKUP()** or a combination of **MATCH()** and **INDEX()**

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a service site where we do the work for you. Please take a minute to update your question with what you have attempted and where you are stuck. We will help you from there.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start here, site no. column is sheet1! G:G, that's the place I want to start typing 3digit site address. sheet2! A:A is where site numbers are sheet2! B:B is where the address is & sheet1! H:H is where I want the address to enter.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use VLOOKUP(), use the following:

=VLOOKUP(G1,Sheet2!A:B,2,false)

Once you have this in cell H1 on Sheet 1, you'll copy it down as far as you need it.

Answer (score -1):

=VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!A1:B1000,2)

Comment: The idea here is to give comprehensive answers others who come along later can also use. If you improve your answer by explaining how the user should implement this answer and provide some reference, it will become valuable to a much wider audience. Take a look at [How do I write a good answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.